# Google Adwords Conversion tracking cookie help!

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-ads-api

I have Google Adwords conversion tracking set up on my domain. Can my domain read the cookie set by Google Adwords conversion script? They use JavaScript to add cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't read it because it's a third-party cookie set by doubleclick.net - so only Goolge can read it. If you use Google Analytics it is possible to read the cookies because they are first-party cookies registered against your domain.